# hangs on boost adjacency list clear

Tags: c++, boost, memory-management

I try to use text detection application written on C++ (https://sites.google.com/site/roboticssaurav/strokewidthnokia), but the code is hanging. I found out that the root of this problem is that one of the functions uses large graph 50 K vertices and 150 K edges, and all code hangs where adjacency list "clear" is called.

```
std::vector< std::vector<Point2d> >
findLegallyConnectedComponents (IplImage * SWTImage,
                                std::vector<Ray> & rays)
{
...
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS> Graph;
...
Graph g(num_of_vertices);
...
}
```

After leaving this function g.clear() will be called, and program hangs on this. How can i rid from this bug? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this problem disappears in release mode, so that is the solution.

Comment: Nice catch... this exact problem had me stumped.

Answer (score 0):

This issue only happend on debug mode.

If you cannot use release mode like me.

You can manual clear m_edges then clear m_vertices in the graph to avoid this issue.

like follow:

```
Graph g;
// .......

// clear it on DEBUG mode to avoid hanges
g.m_edges.clear();
g.m_vertices.clear();
g.clear();
```